# How to apply custom color theme for Material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I am trying to apply my custom theme for my React Js application I am using Material UI.

Please explain me step by step.

I am very new in ReactJs and Material UI. It is my first project. Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned there're docs about this http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes but I want to provide a few easy steps wich may be useful for beginners:

#### 1 Theme creating

You can use [storybook-addon-material-ui](https://github.com/sm-react/storybook-addon-material-ui) project to create your theme. The fastest way is to do it just on the [demo page](https://sm-react.github.io/react-theming/?theme-ind=0&theme-sidebar=true&theme-full=true&selectedKind=Material-UI&selectedStory=Components&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=sm%2Fstorybook-addon-material-ui%2Fmaterial-panel) and download your theme as a JSON file.

#### 2 Apply theme

I assume that you already have a structure like this:

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
  <MyMaterialComponents />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

so your next step is:

```
import myTheme from './myTheme.json';

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={myTheme}>
  <MyMaterialComponents />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

But please note that if you have non-material components in your `<MyMaterialComponents />` theme settings won't affect them.
If you still have questions after that you may find useful [`react-theming`](https://github.com/sm-react/react-theming) project

**Update 2020**

Here is updated documentation https://github.com/react-theming/storybook-addon#using-with-material-ui

Comment: The theme object there is no longer compatible with the latest mui. Any better way?

Comment: Please read documentation here https://github.com/react-theming/storybook-addon#using-with-material-ui